# Does GT.M save database operation command in logs file

Tags: mumps

I see that have some logs file create by gt.m but just only about mupip rundown or recover information

```
> root@localhost:/tmp/fis-gtm/V6.2-002_x86_64# ll total 68 drwxrwxrwt 2
> root root 4096 Jul 14 16:22 ./ drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 13
> 14:32 ../
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jul 13 14:33 root_20150713073215UTC-20150713073319UTC_mupip_rundown
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  278 Jul 13 14:32 root_20150713073215UTC_mupip_recover
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jul 14 11:11 root_20150713073407UTC-20150714041129UTC_mupip_rundown
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  278 Jul 13 14:34 root_20150713073407UTC_mupip_recover
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  278 Jul 14 09:46 root_20150714024647UTC_mupip_recover
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jul 14 09:49 root_20150714024820UTC-20150714024941UTC_mupip_rundown
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  278 Jul 14 09:48 root_20150714024820UTC_mupip_recover
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   77 Jul 14 09:55 root_20150714025001UTC-20150714025500UTC_mupip_rundown
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  291 Jul 14 09:50 root_20150714025001UTC_mupip_recover
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jul 14 10:03 root_20150714030230UTC-20150714030331UTC_mupip_rundown
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  311 Jul 14 10:02 root_20150714030230UTC_mupip_recover
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jul 14 14:35 root_20150714030424UTC-20150714073509UTC_mupip_rundown
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  260 Jul 14 10:04 root_20150714030424UTC_mupip_recover
```

Where do I find logs about GTM command like : SET ^,WRIRE....?

Answer (score 2):

Normal commands (Set, Write) are part of the core programming language and are not logged; they are journalled if they read or write something to disk. The question is what are you looking for?

Comment: Assume that I have GT.M system and I want to know which operations ( set,write...) is operated on my database for monitoring ,If assume that you run this command : SET ^ACCOUNT("John","Salary")=100000, then I (as administrator) can see this command logging somewhere, similar to RDMS logging to log file.Is there any way to see that ?

Comment: @Ryo, as Sam says, use the journal file. Turn on journaling. Run your application. Use the MUPIP JOURNAL EXTRACT command to find the information about database updates in your journal files. Read all about it in the GT.M Administration and Operations Guide - go to [link](http://fis-gtm.com) and click on the User Documentation tab. You may also find the GT.M Acculturation Workshop useful - go to [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fis-gtm/files/GT.M%20Acculturation%20Workshop/) and get the latest version (currently 0.9).

Comment: Thank for your information @K.S. Bhaskar. I got that

Comment: Hi Mr. K.S. Bhaskar, I could extract almost  commands impact to my GT.M database from journal files.They are SET ,KILL..Now I want to see ZWRITE commands (command show my data ,similar to SELECT command in RDBMS), Does it store in anywhere ? , I guess that it not in journal files

Comment: What you are after exactly? ZWRITE shows what's currently in the database. The SET and WRITE are the log of how you got there.

Comment: I want to know all of CRUD operations on database for monitoring ,I found a way that I can read them from memory of a running gtm process